# Silverlight UserControl Library

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight

I created a usercontrol in a silverlight library. This control will be used among several different projects. It uses a reference to a third party dll. When I try and drag the control from the toolbox it throws an error about finding the third party control.

If i add a referene to my application to the third party and then add my control it works fine. My question is there any way that when i add this usercontrol I can force it to add the thrid party reference to the project its being added to first?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you could do this with a NuGet package but don't know of any way to do it by just adding a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article explains what registry keys to set

http://www.ningzhang.org/2009/04/30/register-silverlight-controls-with-visual-studio-and-blend/

> One caveat: if the registered assemblies depend on other assemblies, those dependent assemblies need to be in the same directory as registered assemblies, or themselves registered under AssemblyFoldersEx as described above.

Comment: I would have to do that for every development machine. I am trying to make this library public